# Installing HDF5-1.8.13 on Solaris 11 - failed

Tags: solaris

I'm trying to install HDF5-1.8.13 on a Virtual Machine running Solaris 11.

After downloading/unzip the source package,

I ran

```
$CC='gcc -m64' ./configure --prefix=[my installation path]
```

The configuration was succesful. (Output file below)

```
  SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
            =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.8.13
                  Configured on: Thu Apr  9 16:46:59 IRDT 2015
                  Configured by: root@Solaris_1
                 Configure mode: production
                    Host system: i386-pc-solaris2.11
              Uname information: SunOS Solaris_1 5.11 11.2 i86pc i386 i86pc
                       Byte sex: little-endian
                      Libraries: static, shared
             Installation point: /export/home/navid/Babak/HDF5

Compiling Options:
------------------
               Compilation Mode: production
                     C Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -m64
                         CFLAGS:
                      H5_CFLAGS: -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wpacked -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Wunreachable-code -Wendif-labels -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wold-style-definition -Winvalid-pch -Wvariadic-macros -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-macros -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-overflow -Wlogical-op -Wlarger-than=2048 -Wvla -Wsync-nand -Wframe-larger-than=16384 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wjump-misses-init -Wunsuffixed-float-constants -Wdouble-promotion -Wsuggest-attribute=const -Wtrampolines -Wstack-usage=8192 -Wvector-operation-performance -Wsuggest-attribute=pure -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions
                      AM_CFLAGS:
                       CPPFLAGS:
                    H5_CPPFLAGS:  -LANG:std  -DNDEBUG -UH5_DEBUG_API
                    AM_CPPFLAGS:
               Shared C Library: yes
               Static C Library: yes
  Statically Linked Executables: no
                        LDFLAGS:
                     H5_LDFLAGS:
                     AM_LDFLAGS:
                Extra libraries:  -lz -lnsl -lsocket -ldl -lm
                       Archiver: ar
                         Ranlib: ranlib
              Debugged Packages:
                    API Tracing: no

Languages:
----------
                        Fortran: no

                            C++: no

Features:
---------
                  Parallel HDF5: no
             High Level library: yes
                   Threadsafety: no
            Default API Mapping: v18
 With Deprecated Public Symbols: yes
         I/O filters (external): deflate(zlib)
         I/O filters (internal): shuffle,fletcher32,nbit,scaleoffset
                            MPE: no
                     Direct VFD: no
                        dmalloc: no
Clear file buffers before write: yes
           Using memory checker: no
         Function Stack Tracing: no
      Strict File Format Checks: no
   Optimization Instrumentation: no
       Large File Support (LFS): yes
```

Bu when i do a $make check i get this error:

```
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
fail=; \
if (target_option=k; case ${target_option-} in  ?) ;;  *) echo "am__make_running_with_option: internal error: invalid"  "target option '${target_option-}' specified" >&2;  exit 1;;  esac;  has_opt=no;  sane_makeflags=$MAKEFLAGS;  if test -n '' && test -n ''; then  sane_makeflags=$MFLAGS;  else  case $MAKEFLAGS in  *\\[\ \     ]*)  bs=\\;  sane_makeflags=`printf '%s\n' "$MAKEFLAGS"  | sed "s/$bs$bs[$bs $bs        ]*//g"`;;  esac;  fi;  skip_next=no;  strip_trailopt ()  {  flg=`printf '%s\n' "$flg" | sed "s/$1.*$//"`;  };  for flg in $sane_makeflags; do  test $skip_next = yes && { skip_next=no; continue; };  case $flg in  *=*|--*) continue;;  -*I) strip_trailopt 'I'; skip_next=yes;;  -*I?*) strip_trailopt 'I';;  -*O) strip_trailopt 'O'; skip_next=yes;;  -*O?*) strip_trailopt 'O';;  -*l) strip_trailopt 'l'; skip_next=yes;;  -*l?*) strip_trailopt 'l';;  -[dEDm]) skip_next=yes;;  -[JT]) skip_next=yes;;  esac;  case $flg in  *$target_option*) has_opt=yes; break;;  esac;  done;  test $has_opt = yes); then \
  failcom='fail=yes'; \
else \
  failcom='exit 1'; \
fi; \
dot_seen=no; \
target=`echo install-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`; \
case "install-recursive" in \
  distclean-* | maintainer-clean-*) list='src test testpar tools . c++ fortran hl perform examples' ;; \
  *) list='src test  tools .    hl perform' ;; \
esac; \
for subdir in $list; do \
  echo "Making $target in $subdir"; \
  if test "$subdir" = "."; then \
    dot_seen=yes; \
    local_target="$target-am"; \
  else \
    local_target="$target"; \
  fi; \
  (CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd $subdir && make  $local_target) \
  || eval $failcom; \
done; \
if test "$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
  make  "$target-am" || exit 1; \
fi; test -z "$fail"
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `install-recursive'
```

Can you point out what went wrong here?

Comment: The actual error is probably just before the `*** Error code 1` line - what's shown currently is just telling you where in the build it failed.

Comment: Also: On Solaris remember to use `gmake` rather than `make`. Your make command should be `MAKE=gmake gmake` to be on the safe side. (not sure it matters in the case at hand though)

Comment: According to [this](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/platforms5.html) the HDFGroup tests the HDF software on Solaris using the Solaris Studio Compiler, not the GNU C/C++ compiler. So you might want to try that compiler instead. It is a [free download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html)